# Remove discovered cards

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, removechild

I'm creating Flash "memory" game, Idea to discover 2 equal cards. Everything is fine, just I need to make that when cards are discovered they will be deleted. Now It stay shown.

When I try:
`removeChild(_card.currentTarget._type);`

I receive error:
`C:\...\MemoryGame.as, Line 202 1119: Access of possibly undefined property currentTarget through a reference with static type Card.`

Here is part of code:

```
    for(var l:Number = 0; l < 2; l++)
    {
        _card = new Card();
        addChild(_card);
        _snow = new Snow();
        _card.setType(_snow);
        _card.x = _cardX;
        _card.y = _cardY;
        _cardX += _card.width + 50;
        _card.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);
        _cards.push(_card);
    }

private function checkCards(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkCards);

    if(_firstCard == undefined)
    {
        _firstCard = event.currentTarget;
    }
    else if(String(_firstCard._type) == String(event.currentTarget._type))
    {
        trace("Match");
        _message = "Match";
        message_txt.text = _message;
        _firstCard = undefined;
        _currentMatches ++;
        removeChild(_card.currentTarget._type);
```

Could you help me?

**Edit:**

When I use: `removeChild(_firstCard)`

I receive error: `TypeError:`

```
Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null. at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild() at MemoryGame/checkCards()[C:\Users\Rimante\Desktop\gerase\gerase\MemoryGame.as:218]`
```

When I use: `removeChild(event.currentTarget);`

I receive error:

```
C:\Users\Rimante\Desktop\gerase\gerase\MemoryGame.as, Line 217  1118: Implicit coercion of a value with static type Object to a possibly unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 removeChild(event.currentTarget as DisplayObject)
 removeChild(_firstCard as DisplayObject)
```

The removal of _firstCard throws an error because you set the var to undefined. remove

```
 _firstCard = undefined;
```

or move this line below the removeChild-lines.

If you want a delay try:

```
function removeCards(firstCard:DisplayObect, secondCard:DisplayObject):void{
    removeChild(firstCard);
    removeChild(secondCard);
}
```

and within you event listener call

```
setTimeout(removeCards, 1000, _firstCard as DisplayObject, event.currentTarget as DisplayObject);
```

and remove the removeChild lines

Comment: Thank you for answer. I updated my first question with error which I get.

Comment: And I updated my answer as well. This whole concept in editing questions and answers is a little bit strange to me :)

Comment: Thank you. Now It removes only second card, I need to remove both (first and second)

Comment: I more question, now immediatly deleting cards and second card isn't shown. How to make a little pause for 1 second before cards deleted? Something like? `var timer1:Timer = new Timer(750, 1);  timer.start();` but It doesn't work.

Comment: you can do this in several ways. Personally I would write a remove Method which receives both MovieClips/Sprites as parameters and call this method via setTimeout.

Comment: Let me UPDATE MY ANSWER :D

Comment: Okay, when you update an accepted answer, it is no longer accepted. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to do:

```
removeChild(event.currentTarget);
```

Also, I think you would need to do:

```
removeChild(_firstCard);
```

Comment: And I think you meant _firstCard

Comment: Thank you for answer. I updated my first question with error which I get.